# How to diferrentiate ids when using angularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created directive when user click on delete button i am trying to print 
Keys so my initial goal is identified the Keys then i have to call different Api's.

How can i check if i have riskKey print Risk information ?

process.html

```
<delete-buttons ids="processDTO.processKey"></delete-buttons>
```

risk.html

```
<delete-buttons ids="riskDTO.rskKy"></delete-buttons>
```

directive.js

```
 angular.module('App').directive('deleteButtons', function () {
  'use strict';
  return{
    restrict:'E',
    scope:{
    id: '=ids'
    },
    template: [
               '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteButton()">Delete</button>'
           ],
   link:function(scope,element,attr){
     scope.deleteButton = function(){
       if(scope.id === processKey) {
         console.log('PROCESS KEY',scope.id);
       } else if(scope.id === rskKy) {
         console.log('RISK KEY',scope.id);
       }
     }
   }     
  }

});
```

Comment: Add one more attribute, type

Comment: Add add another attribute but don't use `type` as that is already used by the browser. Maybe 'dto-type`.